# Git: Change the Modification property of a file

Tags: git

Our code uses a database, a particular schema version of this db is associated with a version number. Let’s say, the current version is 95.

Each time a developer’s feature branch changes the db schema, he/she creates a corresponding update file. Now, if I change the schema in my branch, I would create a file `update_96`.  But, if someone else updates the db at the same time and her/his feature branch is merged to develop before, a file with that name is already present. A merge or rebase would create a conflict.

Now, the two new `update_96` files are independent: I thought, I would just have to rename mine to `update_97` and the rebase would be fine. But git “knows” that my `update_97` was before `update_96` and tries to merge these two files anyways. I guess, the reason is the Modification property Renamed-modified.

How do I change this property to Added? Various experiments with deleting/readding `update_97` in separate commits did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git does not have file properties.  Each commit simply stores a snapshot of files.  If commit A has a file `X` and commit B has a file `Y`, those are two separate commits with two separate files.

When Git compares two commits, it's like comparing two pictures in one of those [Spot the Difference games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference).  There's a snapshot on the left, and a snapshot on the right.  Each snapshot is made up of files.  So let's put commit A on the left and commit B on the right, and compare:

- If commit A has both `X` and `Y`, and commit B has only `Y`, then the result of comparing commit A vs commit B will be: *file `X` was deleted* (plus whatever's different in `Y`).
- If commit A has only `X`, and commit B has both `X` and `Y`, then the result of comparing A vs B will be: *file `Y` was created* (along with whatever is different in `X`).
- But if commit A has `X` (and not `Y`), and commit B has `Y` (and not `X`), *now* things get interesting.  There's a pair of files where the *names* don't match, but maybe the *contents still match*.

It's this third case where Git will try to *guess* whether the file was renamed (and maybe modified as well).  Git will see the file as renamed (and otherwise unchanged) if the contents match exactly, bit-for-bit, 100% identically.  But that's not good enough for real world cases, so Git will *also* see the files renamed if the contents merely match about 99%, or 80%, or even 51%.

This rename-detection is a matter of determining the file's identity.  Is file `X` in A the same as file `Y` in B, or not?  In general, this is a very hard problem (see the philosophical problem of the [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus)).  Git has a concrete answer: it computes a *similarity index*, a number between 0% similar and 100% exact-match, and decrees a file to be *renamed*—i.e., the same file—if an unmatched left-side file is at least 50% similar to an unmatched right-side file.  Files with name-matches are already paired up as "the same file", so this only applies to cases like the above with files `X` and `Y`.

This "50% similar" is just a *default*, though.  If your migration is, say, 62% similar to the other guy's migration, while all other files that really *should* be detected as "renamed" are more-similar, you can *raise the threshold*.  (With `git diff`, you can also turn rename detection off entirely.  In fact, in older versions of Git, it *defaults* to "off", and must be turned *on* with `-M`.  The default switched to "on" in Git 2.9.)

Now, in the above, I keep talking about `git diff`, while you're doing `git rebase` and `git merge`.  But `git rebase` is really a series of cherry-pick operations, and each cherry-pick is a merge, while `git merge` is of course a merge too (well, it is except when it's a "fast-forward", which is not a merge at all).  Hence **everything you are doing involves Git's internal merge engine.**  This means that you need to understand *how* Git's merge engine works, which is actually quite simple:

- A merge operation has three inputs: a *merge base*—let's call this *B*—and a left side *L* and a right side *R*.  The left side *L* commit is the `--ours` one, and the *R* commit is the `--theirs` one.
- To perform the merge, Git compares the merge base against each of the two sides:

  ```
  git diff --find-renames <B> <L>   # what we changed
  git diff --find-renames <B> <R>   # what they changed
  ```

  Git then *combines the two sets of changes* into one big change to apply to *B*.  Merge conflicts occur when the two sets of changes touch identical files in identical places—which of course requires solving the Ship of Theseus "which of these are the same files" philosophical problem, but that's what the `--find-renames` above is for.

  (And, of course, if Git *does* find renames, you can have rename/rename conflicts, or rename/delete conflicts.  But you don't have to worry about this until it happens.  If only one "side" of these two diffs—one B-vs-whatever—renames a file, Git combines the changes by taking the rename.)
- Having combined the changes, Git applies them to the contents of *B* to produce the merge result.  If all goes well, Git can commit the result directly.  If there are conflicts, Git does the best it can anyway, writes the *conflicted* changes into your work-tree, and stops with a merge conflict (and leaves all three version of each input file in the index).  You get to clean up the mess.

In your particular case, what is going wrong is that Git is detecting renames when you don't want it to.  If the two files match 100% bit-for-bit, Git is still going to detect those renames, but in that case, it's usually harmless.  This sort of this is normally only a problem when Git guesses wrong because a file is just a little too similar, or the reverse case when it's just not quite similar enough.

Fortunately, just as with `git diff`, you can *control* the similarity threshold.  The `git merge` and `git rebase` commands take what Git calls *strategy-option options*, which I think is a terrible name; I call them *extended options* since the letter for them is `-X` (eXtended).  One of these is `-X find-renames=threshold`.  So, if the *good* renames are all at least 90% similar, and the *bad* rename is only 62% similar, doing:

```
git merge ... -X find-renames=90 ...
```

will stop Git from detecting the "wrong" rename.

Of course, if some "good" rename is at 51% while some "bad" rename is at 99%, this does not help.  And without knowing what the actual numbers are, how do you know what to use for `-X find-renames`?  The answer is to do those `git diff`s yourself:

- Find the merge base.  For `git merge`, use `git merge-base --all`.  For cherry-pick, the merge base is the parent of the commit being copied.  Rebase uses cherry-pick, so the merge base for each commit to be copied is that commit's parent.  Find the commit-pair where the "rename" (that is not really a rename) occurs, and use its parent.
- Now that you have the merge base, compare it to the interesting commits (the left and right sides of the merge), using `git diff`.  Git will tell you what the similarity index is for the commits where the rename was detected.  (If you have an older Git version, be sure to use `-M50` or set `diff.renames` to `true`, so that `git diff` will do rename detection.)

The output of this process will tell you what number to use for your rename threshold.  Use any number that all the good renames will meet or exceed, but the bad ones won't.

There are still some issues.  In particular, if you're doing a rebase, that does a whole series of cherry-picks.  The `--ours` or left side of each merge is the commit onto which the cherry is being picked, and you don't know what that will be until you've finished copying the previous commit, because rebase builds the *new* commit chain one commit at a time.  That is, the input *L* commit is the output from the *previous* cherry-pick.  (This is why some rebases keep repeating the same merge conflicts over and over again.)

Still, this is the general method by which you can solve each problem using the tools Git gives you.  (In practice, you can often just guess: a bad match means the default 50% is too accepting, so just move halfway to strict, or 75%, and retry.  A missed match means it's too strict, so move halfway to permissive, or 25%, and retry.)

(Note that `-X find-renames` is the new spelling; with very old versions of Git, it is `-X rename-threshold`.  Check your local `git merge` documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a git attribute of `-merge` for these files, which would prevent automatic merges altogether.

To do that, you'd add a line like

```
update_* -merge
```

to your `.gitattributes`

See: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_performing_a_three_way_merge

A fancier solution would define and set a custom merge driver (also described in the above link)

Comment: That woudl disable merging completely. I just want to prevent merging in the given rare case